# In F#, return true if expression matches pattern?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I am looking for a shorter/neater way of doing the equivalent of the following (for any pattern known at compile time):

```
let f x = match x with | ['A'::_] -> true ; | _ -> false
```

is there a way of doing this in general, i.e. return true iff an expression matches a given pattern?

Answer (score 10):

You could shorten it slightly using `function`:

```
let f = function ['A'::_] -> true | _ -> false
```

Comment: One step closer, but that's it isn't it? No syntax for converting a pattern matching or not to true/false, and no way to pass in a 'pattern' to another function to build one..?

Answer (score 4):

In f#, patterns are not values themselves, and there is no mechanism for converting them to values(*). So, no, there is no neater way.

That said, you may have other options depending on *why* you're interested in checking whether a pattern matches. Caring about whether a pattern matches but not about which values were matched seems a bit unusual to me, so maybe there's an opportunity for refactoring.

As a simple example, suppose you're doing this:

```
let t = match e with <pattern> -> true | _ -> false 
...
if t then
    (* Do something. *)
else 
    (* Do something else. *)
...
```

In that case, you could consider instead doing this:

```
...
match e with 
  <pattern> -> (* Do something. *)
| _         -> (* Do something else. *)
...
```

(Supposing the test happens only once, of course.)

(*) Ignoring [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353491.aspx) and [quotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You may be thinking of an Active Pattern here, specifically its single-case form. It would allow you to create a pattern which returns a boolean value:

```
let (|F|) = function 
    | ['A'::_] -> true
    | _ -> false

let (F x) = [['A']] // val x : bool = true
```

The Active Pattern can be parameterized. Of the (n + 1) arguments it accepts, the first n get passed to the syntactic function, and the last argument is the value matched.

```
let (|G|) e = function
    | [d::_] when d = e -> true
    | _ -> false

let (G 'A' y) = [['A']] // val y : bool = true
```